# Paymill: Do a subscription and later get the subscriptions and corresponding transactions via client_id (PHP)

Tags: php, transactions, subscription, paymill

I have written a script for our application to allow users to make a subscriptions for a product (either on monthly basis or on yearly basis)

Now I have a few questions that I can't find either here or in the paymill documentation:

1st: When I create a subscription for a user with all the necessary information, How can I find out if the subscription was successful? Is there not an initial transaction or do transactions only get made AFTER the interval? For example:

This is my code:

```
        $description = $_POST['client-email'];
        $email = $_POST['client-email'];
        $clientsObject = new Services_Paymill_Clients(PAYMILL_API_KEY, PAYMILL_API_HOST);
        $client        = $clientsObject->create(array(
            'email'       => $email,
            'description' => $description
            ));

        $params = array(
            'token' => 'justatesttokenthatiputhere',
            'client' => $client['id']
        );

        $paymentsObject = new Services_Paymill_Payments(PAYMILL_API_KEY, PAYMILL_API_HOST);

        $creditcard = $paymentsObject->create($params);
        //die("Amount: ".$_POST['card-amount-int']." Domain: ".$subdomain);
        $params = array(
            'amount'   => $_POST['card-amount-int'],       // E.g. "4200" for 42.00 EUR
            'currency' => 'EUR',        // ISO 4217 
            'interval' => '1 '.$_POST['interval-selected'],      // Options: "week", "month" and "year"
            'name'     => $_POST['clientId']
        );


        $offersObject  = new Services_Paymill_Offers(PAYMILL_API_KEY, PAYMILL_API_HOST);
        $offer         = $offersObject->create($params);

        //die(print_r($offer));

        $params = array(
            'client'   => $client['id'],
            'offer'    => $offer['id'],
            'payment'  => $creditcard['id']
        );
        //die(print_r($offer));
        $subscriptionsObject = new Services_Paymill_Subscriptions(PAYMILL_API_KEY, PAYMILL_API_HOST);
        $subscription        = $subscriptionsObject->create($params);

        $clients = $clientsObject->getOne($client['id']);

        $transactions = $transactionsObject->get();

        $subscriptions = $subscriptionsObject->get();
```

I get the feeling, that for example the client_id, subscriptions_id and everything: I don't get them in $subscriptionsObject->get(); for example. I have the feeling that I may get a positive response, but that they are not saved? How can I verify this? Or do I have maybe forgotten something in my code?

2.Question: Can I get the subscriptions of a client with only the client_id (filter by client_id)? And if so: how can I then get the corresponding transactions (to check for their status)?

3.Question: How can I test, if for a subscription, the future payment verification will work? I mean, as far as I understood, we have to check on our site, if a payment has been made and was successful, lets say every month if we choose an interval of 1 Month. How can we verify this?

4.Considering the transactions: According to the documentation: Transactions associated to a subscription have the subscription ID in their description field. But I can't find any of those cases in $transactionsObject->get(); Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I would be glad if someone would point me to the right direction or even give me an example code, as I do find, that these details are not really explained in the documentation of paymill

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have not specified a trial period, then Paymill will execute a transaction as soon as you create the subscription. This transaction has the description "Subscription#...." and has a status (closed being "successful"). You can test this behavior on the Cockpit, by creating some test data there. If you have specified a trial period, the only way to get a feedback once a transaction was made is by using webhooks. You can subscribe to the "subscription.succeeded" and "subscription.failed" events.

2) You can make a request to GET a specified client, which includes all the subscriptions that this client has. See this: https://www.paymill.com/de-de/dokumentation/referenz/api-referenz/#client-object

3) As hinted in the first point, you can create a webhook :-)

4) I'd suggest to just browse to the Cockpit (https://app.paymill.com/de-de , no need to login or register) and setup the data like this:

- Offer 1, no trial period, 42 EUR
- Client 1, with a valid payment method (use the 4111 1111 1111 1111 credit card number)
- Subscription for client 1 for offer 1

Once you finish the third step, there should be a transaction on the "Transactions" page. The description of the transaction will contain something like this "Subscription#sub_f6cd00e38309d80e0cad Offer 1"

If your code is not generating a transaction that contains a description like that, then there's something wrong and you'd need to check what are the HTTP calls being made by your code.